# Update field while inserting non-unique rows using Mysql

Tags: mysql

While insert, I need to update a given field if the value of another field already exist.

`Eg:
fieldone | fieldtwo
 1       | New
 2       | New
 1       | Old`

Here fieldone is not unique and fieldtwo values should get updated while value of fieldone gets repeated.
If again 1 comes in fieldone, we should update the fieldtwo value as 'Old' instead of 'New'.

Is there any way to do this using only Mysql?(with out using any other language)

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes this could be done using trigger, check for `before insert trigger`

Comment: Thanks Abhik for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works at last :)

```
INSERT INTO table_name(fieldone, fieldtwo) SELECT 'valueone', IF(COUNT(fieldone)=0, 'new', 'old') FROM table_name WHERE fieldone='valueone';
```

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks all for your replies :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Insert into table_name values(VAL_FIELDONE ,  
    (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(VAL_FIELDONE) = 0 
    THEN 'NEW'  ELSE 'OLD' END))
```

OR

```
 Insert into table_name values(VAL_FIELDONE ,  
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(FIELDONE) = 0 ,'NEW','OLD') from table_name where
FIELDONE = VAL_FIELDONE))
```

Here VAL_FIELDONE is value you want to insert in fieldone column, and filedtwo value will be old or new accordingly. The select will return 'NEW' if  fieldone is a new value and 'OLD' otherwise

Comment: Thanks prateek for your reply. From which column does COUNT(VALUE1) is calculated? No column name like fieldone or fieldtwo is mentioned.

Comment: @George  I have edited my answer according to your column names, fieldone,fieldtwo

Comment: sorry, that's not what I mean. I asked from which column does the count(ANYVALUE) gets calculated. There are two columns in my sample table say: fieldone and fieldtwo; If we mention COUNT(ANYVALUE), from which column the COUNT value gets calculated? Will it automatically select from fieldone?

Comment: @George Yes, it will automatically calculate the fieldtwo column value depending upon what you insert as fieldone value. It the value of fieldone is a new entry then fieldtwo column value will be 'New' , and if the value already exists , fieldtwo column value will be 'Old'

Comment: It will automatically calculate the fieldtwo column value based on the IF condition, that's right. I'm was asking about the SELECT part, inside the IF condition. i.e. COUNT(VAL_FIELDONE) <- from which column is this get selected? will it check in both columns?

Comment: @George I have done some changes in query regarding your question

Comment: I received this error message while trying that insert: "you can't specify target table for update in from clause while insert"